# Converting x,y,zone coordinates to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: c#, google-maps, latitude-longitude, bing-maps, utm

I want to convert my x,y,zone coordinate to latitude-longitude in c#.how can i do that???
i find some function in net  but they doesnt work properly.plz help me.
if my country is important i live in Iran.

for example: i give this x,y,zone: 271740.00,3250740.00,40

it gives me this [[this site]](http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html): long,lat:54.648498425894694,29.36515026502202,0

Comment: Just _doesnt work properly_ does **not** an enough information about a problem. Can you please be more specific about it?

Comment: Did you try the library referred to in the accepted answer, rather than blindly copying unreadable, badly written code and then coming here to ask why it doesn't work?

Comment: I cant find refrence function about converting.can u help me???

Comment: Do you know in what format are written your zone coordinate ?

Comment: No.I dont have any geograpghic information but our area zone is 38-39-40 just this three number(iran)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good coordinate converter is this one: [Proj](https://proj.org/)
It is written in C, In order to use it in C#, you can use this wrapper: [.NET wrapper for Proj4](http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/)

Another very good library written in C# is [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial)

Other projects are [Proj4Net](https://github.com/shanhuashuiqing/proj4net) and [Proj.Net](http://projnet.codeplex.com/), however I don't know their quality, perhaps they are just copy/paste of other projects. For sure they are all inspired by the original Proj4 project.

Answer (score 1):

[CoordinateSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoordinateSharp/) does conversions like this.

Example

```
 UniversalTransverseMercator utm = new UniversalTransverseMercator("T", 32, 233434, 234234);
 Coordinate c = UniversalTransverseMercator.ConvertUTMtoLatLong(utm);
```

Your lat/long values can be found in the `Coordinate` object